# Understanding bash script

Tags: bash, for

I'm a bit stuck trying to understand the following script from a book:

```
values=(39 5 36 12 9 3 2 30 4 18 22 1 28 25)
numvalues=${#values[@]}

for (( i=0; i < numvalues; i++ )); do 
    lowest=$i

    for (( j=i; j < numvalues; j++ )); do
        if [ ${values[j]} -le ${values[$lowest]} ]; then
            lowest=$j
        fi
    done

    temp=${values[i]}
    values[i]=${values[lowest]}
    values[lowest]=$temp
done

for (( i=0; i < numvalues; i++ )); do
    echo -ne "${values[$i]}\t"
done

echo
```

The script is performing a selection sort on the numbers in the array, and is ultimately sorting them in correct numerical order. According to the book:

> the outer i for loop is for looping over the entire array and pointing
>   to the current 'head' (where we put any value we need to swap). The
>   variable lowest is set to this index.

I understand this part, and I guess the value of lowest on the first iteration will be index 0, and the value 39.

What I am struggling to understand is how the inner j loop is working. The book says:

> it compares the remaining elements with the value at lowest; if a
>   value is less than lowest is set to the index of that element.

I can't get my head around how the value of `j` is any different to the value of `i`. To my mind if `j=i`, which is on first iteration 0, then `j` is also equal to 0. I guess this must change on the second and subsequent iterations. I know that the value of `j` must differ from the value of `i`, as this is what the `[ ${values[j]} -le ${values[$lowest]} ]` part of the script is calculating.

Does this work because of the `j=i` and subsequent `j++` part of the inner for loop? If `j=i`, and on the second iteration if `i=1`, does this mean that `j++` is equal to 2?

New Comment:

On thinking further about this script. I can see how j=i+1 would work in the inner loop. In the first iteration i would be 0 and j would be 1, so this would compare the values of the first and second element. On further iterations, i=1 and j=2, i=2 and j=3 etc….

However, in the script as it is written I can’t quite see how it works. On first iteration i=0 and j=0. So the first value in the array is compared with itself. Surely on second iteration i=1 and j=2, so this would compare the second and third values. What I can’t see is how index 0 was compared with index 1 ie. 39 compared against 5. Surely the second iteration skips this as it compares 5 against 36.

Answer (score 2):

> To my mind if j=i, which is on first iteration 0, then j is also equal
>   to 0.

Correct, for each of the first iterations of the inner loop, `j` will be equal to `i`.

> I guess this must change on the second and subsequent iterations.

Also correct (for the inner loop). For the first iteration of the inner loop, `j` will have whatever value `i` holds in that iteration of the outer loop.

> I know that the value of `j` must differ from the value of `i`, as this is
>   what the `[ ${values[j]} -le ${values[$lowest]} ]` part of the script
>   is calculating.

From the second iteration (of the inner loop) onwards.

> If `j=i`, and on the second iteration if `i=1`, does this mean that
>   `j++` is equal to 2?

Also correct, for the second iteration of the inner loop<sup>1</sup>.

Now, for each of the first iterations of the inner loop, `i`, `j` and `lowest` are all the same. Why? `lowest` was already set to `i`. `j` is set to `i` at the beginning of the iteration, and the test that follows will set `lowest` to `j`, which is `i`, because it is comparing the same elements. So, the first iteration of that inner loop is pointless, it could have started from `i+1` without any problem. However, it is not an error, just unnecessary.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Technically, `j++` will be `1`, not two, since `++` after the variable, called a *post increment* operator, increases the value after the variable has been evaluated for the expression. `j` will be 2 *after* the expression has been evaluated.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That inner loop `for (( j=i; j < ...` seems buggy, as by contrast "Algorithms" (4th edition, Sedgewick & Wayne) uses:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < ...
```

for their selection sort example.